# Pandas does not filter properly by row condition

Tags: python, pandas

I have a df with ID, Date, and DIM.
DIM is int64

When I do:

```
df2=df.loc[df.DIM>50]
```

There are rows in df with DIM>50 that are not part of df2.

Does any one know why?

If I do :

```
df3=df.loc[df.ID==6]
```

It returns the rows with the ID that has DIM>57 and was not part of df2 above.
Then, if I do:

```
df4=df3.loc[df3.DIM>50]
```

It works... Now, the rows originally excluded in df2 with DIM>50 are now in df3.

Comment: "*There are rows in df with DIM>50 that are not part of df2.*' -> please show us a reproducible example. Are you sure you have integers and not strings?

Comment: Kindly provide a snippet of your dataframe and expected output

Comment: Your question needs a minimal reproducible example consisting of sample input, expected output, actual output, and only the relevant code necessary to reproduce the problem. See [How to make good reproducible pandas examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples) for best practices related to Pandas questions.

Comment: Can you provide us with outputs of `df.info()` and `df.isnull().sum()` ?